# How to fix a flex container to ratain the width and height of cards intact and other alignment issue?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I really need your help here. I am very new to this Front End work and have submitted few questions related to this issue.

I am building an UI using react js. Where i display the cards for products and resources. I am using display flex in the container and making it center justified. But the issue is

- I want to limit 4 cards per row
- The width and hight of the cards to remain same irrespective of screen size
- I have two sections where i display cards, at first place i am displaying 8 cards and the second place i am displaying two. I want the cards should start from same position in the UI
- Alignment issue with header section

Here is the code and Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/527rx9

Here is how it looks currently

[image]

I got some feedback from other questions i had pasted to use width to 1500px. But deep down i feel , not a right way and will break in some screen. But in this case as well i see alignment issues. below image by using 1500px in container width

[image]
Really need your help here to have a fix around it. If you are willing please paste the codesandbox or anyother link with a working code.

Comment: CSS Grid will get you exactly what you want

Comment: a low-effort alternative would be to give '.card-container' a max-width eg 'max-width: 1400px;'

Comment: You say you want the card size to remain the same irrespective of screen size. What should happen when the screen doesn't fit 4 cards? Also, what does *"I want the cards should start from same position in the UI"* actually mean?

Comment: do you mean that in the second block you want the two cards to be on the left in the same position as the first two of the block above?

Comment: *"But in this case as well i see alignment issues"* can mean at least 5 different things. How do you expect us to know what you mean?

Comment: See if [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-thompson-241lw5?file=/src/app.css) is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Yousaf.. This is what i wanted

Comment: Hi yosaf, How to align the headers also according to cards start position?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your container css for the grid:

```
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* width: 1500px; */
}
```

It's no problem setting a max-width and you should do it, however dont use a specific width, instead set the max-width to 1500px if that's your desired max-width

```
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1500px;
}
```

However i would recommend putting all the content below your banner inside of a div

```
<div class="content-container">
```

And setting the CSS of that one to the max-width in order to avoid some indentation problems to solve this specific problem